# How do you use MultipleChoiceField with a get request?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to have a form submitted with multiple values for one field that allows querying with an or statement. I have the MultipleChoiceField working that submits a get request as follows:

```
<QueryDict: {u'Selection': [u'option1', u'option2']}>
```

When I try and read an individual result from the request with

```
post = request.GET.get('Selection')
```

only 'option2' is returned and not the other selected item(s).

How can I turn the MultipleChoiceField into a query that selects 'option1' or 'option2'? Is there a better method of turning a form submission into an 'or' query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` is a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object, which has special behavior when multiple values are submitted in the HTTP `GET` for the same key. To get all of them, use the [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method. Alternatively, just use a form - the form field will collect the multiple values for you.